# How do i get the exe file name of the second added project? EDITED

Tags: c#

In Form1 i did this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;



namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1 f1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


                    MessageBox.Show("Oops something went wrong sorry");
                    f1 = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1();



        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Where f1 is the second project i just added.

Now i added the seocnd project as a reference.

In the second project i did:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[] hardDrivedInfo;
        string applicationFileName; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            applicationFileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

But the applicatioFileName show me the path of the exe file of the first project while i need to get the directory + file name of the second project wich is in directory: `D:\C-Sharp\test\test\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe`

The directory of the first project is: `D:\C-Sharp\test\test\test\bin\Debug\test.exe`

But i need to make that applicationFileName will show: `D:\C-Sharp\test\test\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe`

EDIT **

What i want to do is to run the first main project then after the messagebox is popup and i close it it will run the second project will copy the second project exe file to another location like D: and will run the exe file of the second project. So if i delete the first project exe file the second one on D: will keep running.

Comment: Why is one executable referencing another executable?  If they have code that they need to share, that code should be extracted into a class library and both applications should reference that library.  Applications referencing each other is unintuitive and messy (as you've discovered).

Comment: @user....it's unclear as to what you want.  Are you saying you want...applicationFileName will show: D:\C-Sharp\test\test\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
in both projects?

Comment: MikeTWebb no i want to get only in the second project the executeable file name of the second project with the full path. In other words i want to copy the second project executeable file name to another hard drive for example D: and then to run this exe file from D: and even if i close or delete the exe of the first project the second one will keep running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text is a bit unclear, but I'm guessing you're trying to get the name of the *referenced* assembly, rather than the one that started the process, right?

Try using [`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx). Then you can get the full path from the `Location` property.

Comment: Avner you right im trying to get the reference executeable file name of the second project rather than the one that started the process. So i tried your idea but i didnt find any property: GetExecutingAssembly() fro Assembly. I did: use System.Reflection; I did Assembly assembly1. Then i did assembly1. but there is no GetExecutingAssembly() Maybe the problem is that im usin vs2010 pro and .net 4.0 ?

Comment: `GetExecutingAssembly` is a static method, so you call it on the `Assembly` type itself. You don't need to define a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using

```
string file = typeof(Form1).Assembly.Location;
```

See [`Assembly.Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx) for more information:

> The location of the loaded file that contains the manifest. If the loaded file was shadow-copied, the location is that of the file after being shadow-copied. If the assembly is loaded from a byte array, such as when using the Load(Byte[]) method overload, the value returned is an empty string ("").

Comment: Tried the Location property it didnt work good. Showed me the first project paths with the path in the end of the second project for some reason.

Comment: @user1363119: Well that's where the assembly was loaded from - it's being copied as part of your build process, but it's showing you the file that was loaded. I can't see how you expect it to know where the file was originally copied *from*.